# Get kinetic diameter of a molecule

Tags: molecular-modeling, software-recommendations

I want to calculate the kinetic diameter of a molecule to estimate if it can fit inside a pore/channel of a microporous material. Do you know any software that would allow me to do this?

I've seen a [similar question on Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_estimate_the_kinetic_diameter_of_a_molecule_from_its_chemical_structure) but they did not arrive at any good conclusion.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!

Comment: To be honest I did not find a good answer for this

Comment: You also took a week to respond and didn't respond to the second part of the comment, so we assume that getting an answer is not very urgent for you, meaning that other unanswered questions can receive priority over this one (hence the closure), but if someone wants to write an answer they are more than welcome to ping me in a comment or to click Flag and write a custom message asking for the question to be re-opned.